# Numpy.apply_along_axis works unexpectedly when applying a function with if else condition

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I had trouble getting unexpected results. The following code reproduces the result in a simplest way(`f` is just a test function):

```
#returns absolute difference between last and first element in an array
def f(arr): 
    return 0 if arr[-1] == arr[0] else abs(arr[-1]-arr[0])

def test_vectorized(test_arr, window = 2):
    T = test_arr.shape[0]
    #create sliding windows
    slide_windows = np.expand_dims(np.arange(window+1), axis=0) + np.expand_dims(np.arange(T - window), axis=0).T
    print(slide_windows)
    slide_values = test_arr[slide_windows]
    print(slide_values)
    #apply function to each sliding window
    return np.apply_along_axis(f, axis=1, arr=slide_values)
```

```
#testing
test_arr = np.array([27.75, 27.71, 28.05, 27.75, 26.55,27.18])
test_vectorized(test_arr, window=3)
```

```
#Output
[[0 1 2 3]
 [1 2 3 4]
 [2 3 4 5]]
[[27.75 27.71 28.05 27.75]
 [27.71 28.05 27.75 26.55]
 [28.05 27.75 26.55 27.18]]
Out[238]:
array([0, 1, 0])
```

The code should return `array([0,1.16,0.87])`, i.e. the absolute difference between first and last element in each of the sliding arrays.
I'm using Jupyter notebook with python 3.8.2. I've spent more than an hour debugging, but seems like there's no problem with the code itself. Could anyone help? Highly appreciated.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is only useful when iterating on 2 out of 3 axes (or for higher dimensios).  For iterating on a 1 or 2 array it adds overhead and unexpected behaviors like this.  It's not worth your time trying to get it working!  It is not a true `numpy` 'vectorization'.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, but creating sliding windows and using np.apply_along_axis is the only vectorized solution I can think of to my problem.

Comment: The problem you hit here is that `apply_along_axis` has to deduce the return dtype, which it does with a trial calculation.  If your function returns an int for the trial the result will be int.

Comment: Let me repeat, `apply_along_axis` is not a vectorized solution.  It just hides python level iteration within a function.

Comment: @hpaulj I see. Thank you for explaining that. So only matrix/vector calculation (multiplication etc.) are considered vectorization?

Comment: This application of `apply_along` is the equivalent of `np.array([f(row) for row in slide_values])`.  I realize your `f` is just illustrative, but `np.abs(slide_values[:,-1]-slide_values[:,0])` is the "vectorized" version, working on all rows at once, rather than iterating through them.

Comment: The 'vectorization' that saves time in `numpy` uses the compiled methods and functions to work with the whole array.  Tools like `np.apply_along_axis` (and `np.vectorize`) allow you to use your own function with arrays in the same way, BUT they still call your function repeatedly, without any compiling.  The resulting code may look pretty, but it does not improve performance.

Comment: @hpaulj  I didn't know that np.vectorize is not a vectorization as well... the name is so confusing. Thank you so much for explaining these!!

Comment: "vectorization" is used in several senses.  `numpy` has fast methods and functions that work with whole arrays (and do `broadcasting`), such as `np.add` (`+`).  `np.vectorize` creates a function that can be called in the same way, but does so without the compilation.  It does have a performance disclaimer, but that's far enough down the docs that users often miss it.  Ignoring its notes about `otypes` can also cause the same sort of error that you encountered with `apply...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `f` returns integers.
you have to use:

```
def f(arr):
    return float(0 if arr[-1] == arr[0] else abs(arr[-1]-arr[0]))

[[0 1 2 3]
 [1 2 3 4]
 [2 3 4 5]]
[[27.75 27.71 28.05 27.75]
 [27.71 28.05 27.75 26.55]
 [28.05 27.75 26.55 27.18]]
[0.   1.16 0.87]
```

P.S

your function `f` can be generalized to simple `return abs(arr[-1]-arr[0])` as it covers the `0` case. You don't need the `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you! Yes the if else statement is just for testing purpose. So in general when the input and output type is not float, then there can be problems with numpy functions?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a problem. The first iteration returns 0, therefore numpy creates array of integer which stays array of integers.